# How to write an analogue to matrix-vector multiplation with an extra dimension in tensor notation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

My background is severely lacking in tensor algebra, and after a few days of looking into tensors I am still not able to even formulate this question quite correctly; my apologies for that. I am aware upper and lower indices are used for a specific purpose in tensor calculus but I will here use them differently.

I have a certain product of a three dimensional array (tensor?) with components $\psi^s_{kl} $ with a matrix with components $\phi^s_l$ which works by multiplying the $s$'th matrix of $\Psi$ with the $s$'th vector of $\Phi$:
\begin{equation} \sum_l \psi^s_{kl} \phi^s_l \end{equation}

My question is whether this kind of product has a name, and if so what is it and how can I write it down using tensor notation. Any other helpful resources for this kind of operation would be appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is called tensor contraction, though to be entirely consistent with standard notation (and its conceptual underpinnings), you really should think through which indices should be subscripts and which should be superscripts.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction

Comment: Thanks @Branimir! I am just a bit confused because it seems usually the super/subscript distinction is made on the basis of co/contravariance which - to my limited understanding - has to do with coordinate transformations (which - if I am doing - I am not doing explicitly so I would have to infer them).

Comment: Co/contravariance is the justification in physics notation, but the heart of the matter is really the duality between vector spaces and their duals, and the way you build more general tensors out of these ingredients—the example given of ordinary matrix multiplication as tensor contraction should be particularly instructive in this regard, as well as the example of taking the trace of a matrix.

Comment: In your case, if you're viewing the result of your procedure as an ordinary vector (i.e., a column vector), then your notation should be $\psi_s^{kl}$, whilst if you're viewing the result of your procedure as a functional or covector (i.e., a row vector), then your notation should be $\psi_{ks}^l$.